# How do I add radial/checkbox values to an object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, each

So I'm trying to iterate through all the values of an HTML form and store them in a hashtable object of sorts.

The HTML for the form is pretty lengthy so I won't paste that here. But here is my JavaScript/jQuery so far:

```
readForm = function () {
    var formValues = {};
        $('form :input').each(function () {
            var input = $(this);
                formValues[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
            });
        console.log(formValues);
    }
```

When I put these values in the form:
https://res.cloudinary.com/merrickcloud/image/upload/v1542089140/fdsa_z9re1e.png

I get this in the console:
https://res.cloudinary.com/merrickcloud/image/upload/v1542089140/fdsafsdaf_tmdib6.png

> Why is the value on the radial and checkbox inputs incorrect? And what is that last undefined property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checkboxes you can use this:

Option 1:

```
$('#checkbox_id').prop('checked'));
```

Option 2:

```
$('#checkbox_id').is(':checked'));
```

Maybe in your case with the loop you can try this:

```
if(input.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
  input.is(':checked'));
}
```

...

The undefined property is maybe the Submit button. Is it like this?

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Profile">
```